# At what difficulty do legandry "sets" start to drop?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do set and legendary items start dropping?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67719/when-do-set-and-legendary-items-start-dropping)

I was wondering at what difficulty setting you would start finding Legendary sets. I ask because I've farmed quite a few Whimsyshire runs yet I have not found a single set item. Is there a specific difficulty that they start dropping on?

Answer (score 0):

I picked up a legendary ring "Manald Heal" in normal mode. I can't remember in what ACT I found it but its required level is 17 and I was able to put it on immediately.

Comment: Manald Heal isn't part of a set. It is just a normal Legendary.