# Are set items dropped in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do set and legendary items start dropping?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67719/when-do-set-and-legendary-items-start-dropping)

I know that rare and legendary items are dropped after a kill or from a chest, but are the green set items also dropped?

I know that you can buy them from in the auction house, but I don't know if they are dropped too?

If you have had experience of this, did you have like very high magic find items?

Thanks.

Comment: Besides Magic Find, you can raise chances a lot by getting 5 Neph Valor stacks and farming elites (at level 60)

Comment: @Alok: True ... But what does MF stand for?

Comment: @Alok: nevermind, lol. Magic Find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they drop or else they wouldn't be on the auction house. They are just like the legendary, they are very rare.

I already got the wizard's off hand and a hand crossbow (danatela) if i remember....but seriously the set items just dont cut it for inferno.

Comment: They don't??? Oh, I was looking at getting Inna's Blessing, etc. for Monk - so you think it's not a good idea?

Comment: You can roll so much better stats on rare items

Comment: *"Of course they drop or else they wouldn't be on the auction house"* - Well, it could be just the plans that drop, while the items themselves have to be crafted.  I thought that's what happened for some items.

Answer (score 5):

Some Set Items are dropped like regularly items.  Some are crafted after a [blacksmithing plan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blacksmith-plan/) is dropped. An example of a crafted Set item is [Hallowed Divide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/hallowed-divide).  To figure out what Set Items are crafted or not, go to [Diablo III Game Guide - Items](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/) and chose the equipment type and choice 'Crafted Item'.  To contrast it to the list of Set Items, choice Set

At the time, most high level rares are better than equivalent set items.  However, there is rumors that both legendary and set items are going to be buffed to become better in an upcoming patch. It is unsure whether that will be just for newly dropped legendary (set/unique) items or all legendary items in the game.

Comment: Terminology tip - `Nerfed to be be better` doesn't make any sense. Nerfing means to make worse or weaken, usually in the context of weakening something in order to balance out a game. Surely you mean buffed :)

Comment: @dpatchery - Poo.  I was writing too fast and my mind couldn't keep up :) +1 for that.

Comment: Regarding the rumors... No no no... Blizz won't do this. Thus far their strategy has been to do the inconceivable, unlikely and least logical in order to make game-play harder and less fun. So, no, won't happen. I mean - seriously! - why would legendary and set pieces ever be better than rares?! That's just too... logical.